# Porting from Oracle to Postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql

Earlier our hosted environments were on Oracle but now we have recently switched to postgres. Porting the tables I believe was successfully since it has been working correct for a long time. I have been actually struggling with porting a procedure but is not working for some reason. I went through the documentation part of the ora2pg but I am not able to crack, which I believe is the last piece of the puzzle.

I've started with this one, which looks like this in Oracle:

```
create or replace
procedure c_audit(anonymous in boolean, aud_level IN varchar)
AUTHID CURRENT_USER IS 

  script varchar2(32000);
  acc_select varchar(100);
  open_cursor integer;
  returnval integer;
  p_id integer;
  a_id integer;
  p_name varchar2(100);
  a_name varchar2(100);
  v_count integer;
  c_count integer;
  doc_count integer;
  curr_user varchar(100);
begin

for i in (select a.a_name a_name, a.a_id, p.name p_name, p.id p_id, ds.username username
from c_account a
inner join c_pro p on a.a_id = p.a_id
inner join c_dat_ds_xref x on p.id = x.p_id
inner join c_data ds on x.id_datasource = ds.id
inner join c_conntypes ct on x.id_conntype = ct.id_conntype
where ct.typeid = 'CAPTURE'
order by a.a_name, p.name)
LOOP
    curr_user := i.username;
    IF anonymous = true
    THEN
        acc_select := 'select ' || '''' || i.a_id || '''' || ' a_id,' || '''' || i.p_id || '''' || ' p_id';

    ELSE
        acc_select := 'select ' || '''' || i.a_name || '''' || ' a_name,' || '''' || i.p_name || '''' || ' p_name';
    END IF;

    IF upper(aud_level) = 'VERBATIM'
    THEN         
          script:= acc_select || '
        , count(distinct d.document_id) docCount 
        , sum(case when v.document_id is null or v.verbatim_type_value = ''NO_VERBATIM_TEXT'' then 0 else 1 end) VerbCount 
        , sum(case when v.document_id is null then (select to_number(prop_value) verbSize 
                                        from c_properties 
                                        where prop_name = ''METERING.STRUCT.ONLY.CHARGE'' 
                                        and id_pro = 0) else v.credits end) CreditCount 
        from ' || i.username || '.p_document d 
        left outer join ( 
                        select vi.document_id, t.verbatim_type_value 
                        , case when dbms_lob.substr(vi.extracted_original,8) = ''<cbnull>''
                          or t.verbatim_type_value = ''NO_VERBATIM_TEXT''
                                        then coalesce(s2.strucCredit, .25)                            
                                        else ceil(vi.extracted_original_size/coalesce(s.verbSize, 2048)) end credits                          
                        from ' || i.username || '.p_verbatim vi 
                        left outer join ' || i.username || '.pd_verbatim_type t on vi.verbatim_type_id = t.verbatim_type_id
                        , ( 
                                        select to_number(prop_value) verbSize 
                                        from c_properties 
                                        where prop_name = ''METERING.MAXSIZE.VERBATIM'' 
                                        and id_pro = 0 
                        ) s 
                        , ( 
                                        select to_number(prop_value) strucCredit 
                                        from c_properties 
                                        where prop_name = ''METERING.STRUCT.ONLY.CHARGE'' 
                                        and id_pro = 0 
                        ) s2 
        ) v on d.document_id = v.document_id';
    ELSE    
        IF upper(aud_level) = 'DOCUMENT'
        THEN
            script:= acc_select || '
            , count(distinct a.document_id) docCount
            , sum(credits) creditCount
            from (
            select d.document_id, ceil(sum(v.extracted_original_size)/coalesce(s.verbSize,2048)) credits
            from ' || i.username || '.p_document d
            inner join ' || i.username || '.p_verbatim v on d.document_id = v.document_id
            inner join ' || i.username || '.pd_verbatim_type t on v.verbatim_type_id = t.verbatim_type_id
            , ( 
                            select to_number(prop_value) verbSize 
                            from c_properties 
                            where prop_name = ''METERING.MAXSIZE.VERBATIM'' 
                            and id_pro = 0 
            ) s 
            where t.verbatim_type_value <> ''NO_VERBATIM_TEXT''
            and dbms_lob.substr(v.extracted_original,8) <> ''<cbnull>''
            group by d.document_id, s.verbSize
            union
            select d.document_id, coalesce(s2.strucCredit, .25)
            from ' || i.username || '.p_document d
            , ( 
                            select to_number(prop_value) strucCredit 
                            from c_properties 
                            where prop_name = ''METERING.STRUCT.ONLY.CHARGE'' 
                            and id_pro = 0 
            ) s2 
            where d.document_id not in (select distinct v.document_id from ' || i.username || '.p_verbatim v)
            union 
            select distinct d.document_id, coalesce(s2.strucCredit, .25)
            from ' || i.username || '.p_document d
            inner join ' || i.username || '.p_verbatim v on d.document_id = v.document_id
            inner join ' || i.username || '.pd_verbatim_type t on v.verbatim_type_id = t.verbatim_type_id
            , ( 
                            select to_number(prop_value) strucCredit 
                            from c_properties 
                            where prop_name = ''METERING.STRUCT.ONLY.CHARGE'' 
                            and id_pro = 0 
            ) s2 
            where (t.verbatim_type_value = ''NO_VERBATIM_TEXT''
            or dbms_lob.substr(v.extracted_original,8) = ''<cbnull>'')
            ) a';
            ELSE
                dbms_output.put_line('Invalid choice for audit level, no audit generated');
                exit;
            END IF;
    END IF;
begin

open_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
        DBMS_SQL.PARSE(open_cursor, script,
                   DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
        IF anonymous = true then
            dbms_sql.define_column(open_cursor,1,a_id);
            dbms_sql.define_column(open_cursor,2,p_id);
        else
            dbms_sql.define_column(open_cursor,1,a_name,100);
            dbms_sql.define_column(open_cursor,2,p_name,100);
        end if;
        dbms_sql.define_column(open_cursor,3,doc_count);
        dbms_sql.define_column(open_cursor,4,v_count);
        IF upper(aud_level) = 'VERBATIM' then
            dbms_sql.define_column(open_cursor,5,c_count);
        end if;
        returnval := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(open_cursor);
        loop
            if dbms_sql.fetch_rows(open_cursor) > 0 then
                IF anonymous = true then
                    dbms_sql.column_value(open_cursor,1,a_id);
                    dbms_sql.column_value(open_cursor,2,p_id);
                    dbms_sql.column_value(open_cursor,3,doc_count);
                    dbms_sql.column_value(open_cursor,4,v_count);
                    IF upper(aud_level) = 'VERBATIM' then
                        dbms_sql.column_value(open_cursor,5,c_count);
                        dbms_output.put_line(a_id || ',' || p_id || ',' || doc_count || ',' || v_count || ',' || c_count);
                    else
                        dbms_output.put_line(a_id || ',' || p_id || ',' || doc_count || ',' || v_count);
                    end if;
                else
                    dbms_sql.column_value(open_cursor,1,a_name);
                    dbms_sql.column_value(open_cursor,2,p_name);
                    dbms_sql.column_value(open_cursor,3,doc_count);
                    dbms_sql.column_value(open_cursor,4,v_count);
                    IF upper(aud_level) = 'VERBATIM' then
                        dbms_sql.column_value(open_cursor,5,c_count);
                        dbms_output.put_line(a_name || ',' || p_name || ',' || doc_count || ',' || v_count || ',' || c_count);
                    else
                        dbms_output.put_line(a_name || ',' || p_name || ',' || doc_count || ',' || v_count);
                    end if;
                end if;
            else
                exit;
            end if;
        end loop;

        exception 
            when others then
            --dbms_output.put_line('Error occured. Please check if the current user has Select access to table ' || curr_user || '.p_document ' || curr_user || '.p_verbatim ' || curr_user || '.pd_verbatim_type');
      dbms_output.put_line('Error occured. Please login as ' || curr_user || ' and run the following:');
      dbms_output.put_line('GRANT SELECT ON ' || curr_user || '.P_DOCUMENT to ' || user ||';');
      dbms_output.put_line('GRANT SELECT ON ' || curr_user || '.P_VERBATIM to ' || user ||';');
      dbms_output.put_line('GRANT SELECT ON ' || curr_user || '.pd_verbatim_type to ' || user ||';');
end;
end loop;
end;
```

Does this procedure appears correct with respect to syntax?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION c_audit(anonymous boolean, aud_level text) RETURNS VOID AS $body$
DECLARE
  script text;
  acc_select text;
  returnval integer;
  p_id integer;
  a_id integer;
  i record;
  p_name text;
  a_name text;
  v_count integer;
  c_count integer;
  doc_count integer;
  curr_user text;
BEGIN
for i in (SELECT a.a_name a_name, a.a_id, p.name p_name, p.id p_id, ds.username username
from c_account a
inner join c_pro p on a.a_id = p.a_id
inner join c_dat_ds_xref x on p.id = x.p_id
inner join c_data ds on x.id_datasource = ds.id
inner join c_conntypes ct on x.id_conntype = ct.id_conntype
where ct.typeid = 'CAPTURE'
order by a.a_name, p.name)
LOOP
    curr_user := i.username;
    IF anonymous = true
    THEN
        acc_select := 'SELECT ' || '''' || i.a_id || '''' || ' AccountID,' || '''' || i.p_id || '''' || ' ProjectID';
    ELSE
        acc_select := 'SELECT ' || '''' || i.a_name || '''' || ' AccountName,' || '''' || i.p_name || '''' || ' ProjectName';
    END IF;
    IF upper(aud_level) = 'VERBATIM' 
    THEN         
          script:= acc_select || '
        , count(distinct d.document_id) docCount 
        , sum(case when coalesce(CAST(v.document_id AS text), '') = '' or v.verbatim_type_value = ''NO_VERBATIM_TEXT'' then 0 else 1 end) VerbCount 
        , sum(case when coalesce(CAST(v.document_id AS text), '') = '' then (SELECT to_number(prop_value,''9999.99'') verbSize 
                                        from c_properties 
                                        where prop_name = ''METERING.STRUCT.ONLY.CHARGE'' 
                                        and id_project = 0) else v.credits end) CreditCount 
        from ' || i.username || '.p_document d 
        left outer join ( 
                        SELECT vi.document_id, t.verbatim_type_value 
                        , case when substr(vi.extracted_original,8) = ''<cbnull>''
                          or t.verbatim_type_value = ''NO_VERBATIM_TEXT''
                                        then coalesce(s2.strucCredit, .25)                            
                                        else ceil(vi.extracted_original_size/coalesce(s.verbSize, 2048)) end credits                          
                        from ' || i.username || '.p_verbatim vi 
                        left outer join ' || i.username || '.pd_verbatim_type t on vi.verbatim_type_id = t.verbatim_type_id
                        , ( 
                                        select to_number(prop_value,''9999.99'') verbSize 
                                        from c_properties 
                                        where prop_name = ''METERING.MAXSIZE.VERBATIM'' 
                                        and id_project = 0 
                        ) s 
                        , ( 
                                        select to_number(prop_value,''9999.99'') strucCredit 
                                        from c_properties 
                                        where prop_name = ''METERING.STRUCT.ONLY.CHARGE'' 
                                        and id_project = 0 
                        ) s2 
        ) v on d.document_id = v.document_id';
        SELECT format(script) into script;
    ELSE IF upper(aud_level) = 'DOCUMENT'
        THEN
            script:= acc_select || '
            , count(distinct a.document_id) docCount
            , sum(credits) creditCount
            from (
            SELECT d.document_id, ceil(sum(v.extracted_original_size)/coalesce(s.verbSize,2048)) credits
            from ' || i.username || '.p_document d
            inner join ' || i.username || '.p_verbatim v on d.document_id = v.document_id
            inner join ' || i.username || '.pd_verbatim_type t on v.verbatim_type_id = t.verbatim_type_id
            , ( 
                            SELECT to_number(prop_value,''9999.99'') verbSize 
                            from c_properties 
                            where prop_name = ''METERING.MAXSIZE.VERBATIM'' 
                            and id_project = 0 
            ) s 
            where t.verbatim_type_value <> ''NO_VERBATIM_TEXT''
            and substr(v.extracted_original,8) <> ''<cbnull>''
            group by d.document_id, s.verbSize
            union
            select d.document_id, coalesce(s2.strucCredit, .25)
            from ' || i.username || '.p_document d
            , ( 
                            select to_number(prop_value,''9999.99'') strucCredit 
                            from c_properties 
                            where prop_name = ''METERING.STRUCT.ONLY.CHARGE'' 
                            and id_project = 0 
            ) s2 
            where d.document_id not in (select distinct v.document_id from ' || i.username || '.p_verbatim v)
            union 
            select distinct d.document_id, coalesce(s2.strucCredit, .25)
            from ' || i.username || '.p_document d
            inner join ' || i.username || '.p_verbatim v on d.document_id = v.document_id
            inner join ' || i.username || '.pd_verbatim_type t on v.verbatim_type_id = t.verbatim_type_id
            , ( 
                            select to_number(prop_value,''9999.99'') strucCredit 
                            from c_properties 
                            where prop_name = ''METERING.STRUCT.ONLY.CHARGE'' 
                            and id_project = 0 
            ) s2 
            where (t.verbatim_type_value = ''NO_VERBATIM_TEXT''
            or substr(v.extracted_original,8) = ''<cbnull>'')
            ) a';
            SELECT format(script) into script;
        ELSE
        SELECT format(script) into script;
        exit;
        END IF;
    END IF;
BEGIN
    IF anonymous = true 
    THEN
        IF upper(aud_level) = 'VERBATIM' 
        THEN
            EXECUTE script into a_id, p_id, doc_count, v_count, c_count;
        ELSE
            EXECUTE script into a_id, p_id, doc_count, c_count;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        IF upper(aud_level) = 'VERBATIM'
        THEN
            EXECUTE script into a_name, p_name, doc_count, v_count, c_count;
        ELSE
            EXECUTE script into a_name, p_name, doc_count, c_count;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS returnval := ROW_COUNT;
        LOOP
            IF returnval > 0
            THEN
                IF anonymous = true
                THEN
                    IF upper(aud_level) = 'VERBATIM'
                    THEN
                        SELECT format ('Information %s, %s, %s, %s, %s', a_id, p_id, doc_count, v_count, c_count);
                    ELSE
                        SELECT format ('Information %s, %s, %s, %s', a_id, p_id, doc_count, c_count);
                    END IF;
                ELSE
                    IF upper(aud_level) = 'VERBATIM'
                    THEN
                        SELECT format ('Information %s, %s, %s, %s, %s', a_name, p_name, doc_count, v_count, c_count);
                    ELSE
                        SELECT format ('Information %s, %s, %s, %s', a_name, p_name, doc_count, c_count);
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            ELSE
                EXIT;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN others THEN
          PERFORM format('Error occured. Please login as %s, %s' ,  curr_user ,  ' and run the following:');
          PERFORM format('GRANT SELECT ON %s.P_DOCUMENT to %s', curr_user, user);
          PERFORM format('GRANT SELECT ON %s.P_VERBATIM to %s', curr_user, user);
          PERFORM format('GRANT SELECT ON %s.pd_verbatim_type to %s', curr_user, user);
END;
END LOOP;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
;
ALTER FUNCTION cb_audit(boolean, text) OWNER TO USER;
-- REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION cb_audit FROM PUBLIC;
```

The error for failure I get is -

ERROR: too many parameters specified for RAISE
Where: PL/pgSQL function "cb_audit" line 145 at RAISE

I found this to be a good link which I used as a [reference](http://www.postgresmigrations.com/database-migration/stored-procedure-tool/exhibit-4-dbms-sql-example)

I believe that for porting DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE, RAISE NOTICE should be the right way. I had encountered another error which was for format of the - to_number(prop_value,'9999.99') which appears right as per the syntax mentioned [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-formatting.html) but then for some reason when I switched to to_number(prop_value,''9999.99''), I did not get the error but not sure why that should be or even if it should work correctly.

The version of Postgres -

PostgreSQL 9.1.10 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3), 64-bit

*Edited:*
I actually attempted to modify this function based on the suggestions from Patrick but due to some reason it is not displaying anything on the screen. I added format() at the end of every script to display the script as but it just executed the code and displays c_audit and null. Though I execute the individual subsql and they do return expected counts and results. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two types of string "building": the concatenation `||` operator and the `%` placeholder. Both are perfectly legal, but use of the [`format()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) is preferred because the code is cleaner and PG guards against things like [SQL-injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com) behind the scenes.

The error you are getting is that one of your `RAISE NOTICE` commands has a number of `%` different from the arguments you supply; forgive me for not looking that up but `line 145` is hard to find here on SO. In general, you should rewrite all of them like so:

```
RAISE NOTICE format('GRANT SELECT ON %I.pd_verbatim_type to %I', curr_user, user);
```

The `%I` placeholder takes a SQL identifier as input: it can not be `NULL` and it will be properly quoted to avoid SQL-injection and keyword collisions. (From your code I take it that `curr_user` is a schema name and `user` is a role name, both SQL identifiers.)

Note also that the `PERFORM` statement in a PL/pgSQL function is a `SELECT` statement that does not return data, but it is executed to examine a side effect, such as asserting that some data exists. As a consequence, there is no `PERFORM` privilege, use `GRANT SELECT` instead.

When quoting in PostgreSQL, SQL-identifiers use double quotes, while string literal values use single quotes. The `to_number()` function definitely requires single quotes.

**A few more points to improve your code:**

(1) The two sub-selects in the dynamic query like this one...

```
'select to_number(prop_value,''9999.99'') strucCredit 
 from c_properties
 where prop_name = ''METERING.STRUCT.ONLY.CHARGE'' 
 and id_project = 0'
```

... are `STABLE`: you always get the same result. Instead of leaving them in the dynamic SQL, create two variables and put the results in them before you do anything else:

```
DECLARE
  ...
  verbSize numeric;
  strucCredit numeric;
BEGIN
  SELECT to_number(prop_value,'9999.99') INTO verbSize 
  FROM c_properties 
  WHERE prop_name = 'METERING.MAXSIZE.VERBATIM' AND id_pro = 0;
  SELECT to_number(prop_value,'9999.99') INTO strucCredit 
  FROM c_properties 
  WHERE prop_name = 'METERING.STRUCT.ONLY.CHARGE' AND id_pro = 0;

  ...
```

Then use the varibale `verbSize` and `strucCredit` in your dynamic SQL. Like this you do these queries just once, instead of a few times *for every iteration*.

(2) All of the dynamic queries need a `GROUP BY 1, 2` clause.

(3) The clause `CASE WHEN coalesce(CAST(v.document_id AS text), '') = '' ...` should be written like `CASE WHEN v.document_id IS NULL ...`, assuming that `v.document_id` can not be an empty string.

(4) You changed your `RAISE NOTICE` statements to `SELECT format(...)`. That latter form produces no output, use `RAISE NOTICE format(...)` instead.

(5) Rewrite your dynamic SQL to use the `format()` function too.

Comment: Is it possible to have two loops within a function return more than 1 output? I was able to follow the recommendations till #3. The RAISE NOTICE format() gives me an error, I would post it here. And for some reason, though the function complies and I put a return script midway to verify the script, the script looks fine but for some reason I guess it is is not populated in the values for the variable in execute